# Is there a Python inbuilt way to know why my thread exited and at what time?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a complex code written in Python which has lot of threads and many try-catch blocks. I am using the Python's threading module for my threads. Is there a Python inbuilt way to know why my thread exited and at what time? There is some race condition in my code which I am unable to narrow down. Printing fault in every except block or printing time explicitly while the thread is exiting adds a considerable amount of logging which I don't want.

Comment: `import time` and add a time logger at the end of every thread?

Comment: If you have thread object - you can have your own subclass that will put try-catch-finally over existing code - there you can add logging - I think this is simplest way to do that

Comment: @Moon As I said, adding time explicitly is very tedious as I have thousands of try catch blocks in. Can I add something to my thread class which will dump it's state before exiting?

Comment: @Jerzyk I have implemented a debug server which dumps the current thread stacks every 5 minutes. After comparing two stack dumps I can see that the thread has exited but cant identify the point where it exited and why. Lot of my try catch blocks have finally blocks printing something in logs but still I have a race condition which exits a thread without printing the reason/stack. So I am looking for some method to write in my base thread class which would dump it's state before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

An example of informative logging based on [this](https://docs.python.org/3.2/howto/logging-cookbook.html), containing all the information you need, and you can change the format and add/remove attributes for more/less information you want to present in the output log.

```
import logging

class ConnInfo:

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        """
        To allow this instance to look like a dict.
        """
        from random import choice
        if name == 'ip':
            result = choice(['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1'])
        else:
            result = self.__dict__.get(name, '?')
        return result

    def __iter__(self):
        keys = ['ip', 'user']
        keys.extend(self.__dict__.keys())
        return keys.__iter__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import choice
    levels = (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL)
    a1 = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger('a.b.c'),
                               { 'ip' : '123.231.231.123', 'user' : 'sheila' })
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s IP: %(ip)-15s Thread: %(threadName)s: %(message)s')
    a1.debug('A debug message')
    a1.info('An info message with %s', 'some parameters')
    a2 = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger('d.e.f'), ConnInfo())
    for x in range(10):
        lvl = choice(levels)
        lvlname = logging.getLevelName(lvl)
        a2.log(lvl, 'A message at %s level with %d %s', lvlname, 2, 'parameters')
```

> Output:
>   2016-07-07 09:13:46,255 a.b.c DEBUG    IP: 123.231.231.123 Thread:
>   MainThread: A debug message 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 a.b.c INFO     IP:
>   123.231.231.123 Thread: MainThread: An info message with some parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 192.168.0.1    
>   Thread: MainThread: A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
>   2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       Thread:
>   MainThread: A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07
>   09:13:46,256 d.e.f WARNING  IP: 192.168.0.1     Thread: MainThread: A
>   message at WARNING level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256
>   d.e.f ERROR    IP: 127.0.0.1       Thread: MainThread: A message at
>   ERROR level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f INFO    
>   IP: 127.0.0.1       Thread: MainThread: A message at INFO level with 2
>   parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 192.168.0.1    
>   Thread: MainThread: A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
>   2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f WARNING  IP: 192.168.0.1     Thread:
>   MainThread: A message at WARNING level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07
>   09:13:46,256 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       Thread: MainThread: A
>   message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256
>   d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 192.168.0.1     Thread: MainThread: A message at
>   DEBUG level with 2 parameters 2016-07-07 09:13:46,256 d.e.f WARNING 
>   IP: 192.168.0.1     Thread: MainThread: A message at WARNING level
>   with 2 parameters